# How to Add a Comment box in a URL that display content based on parameter passed , in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, comments

I have a URL www.example.com/view/. It display different content based on the parameter passed to it using GET.
Now i want to add a comment box for each view in wordpress. 
That is if a user click on a certain picture, with id 12, the user is redirecte to
"www.example.com/?pic_id=12/ " and i want to add a comment to this specific picture.

i tried to add 
 `<?php comment_form(); ?>`
as well as 
`<php comment_template(); ?>`

So the problem is the comment is displayed as a whole for the "www.example.com/view" instead of the id passed to the url.
How do i achieve it, displaying different comment box for different content based on the URL parameter in wordpress?